# Client on non-admin user can't communicate using net.pipe with services

Tags: wcf, named-pipes, netnamedpipebinding

I have a client app that hosts a WCF service using net.pipe protocol. The client can't communicate with other WCF services which are running under the admin user.

I have read that you can't communicate using net.pipe between different users.

Is there way to by pass it?

Answer (score 10):

> I have read that you can't communicate using net.pipe between
>   different users.

This isn't true in general. Here is a summary of what I think you are referring to:

If you are running on an operating system earlier than Windows Vista there is no problem: any process should be able to host a WCF net.pipe service accessible to any other local process.

If you are running on Windows Vista or later, a WCF net.pipe service will only be accessible to processes running in the same logon session (e.g. within the same interactive user's session) **unless** the process hosting the WCF service is running with the elevated privilege SeCreateGlobalPrivilege.

Windows Services run in their own logon session, and have the privilege SeCreateGlobalPrivilege, so self-hosted and IIS-hosted WCF net.pipe services are visible to processes in other logon sessions on the same machine.

In most scenarios I have come across where this is an issue, the workaround is to always host the WCF service in a Windows Service, using a duplex contract if necessary to reverse the client and server roles during an interaction session.

See also:

- [Minimum OS Permissions required to create named pipe (WCF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098549/minimum-os-permissions-required-to-create-named-pipe-wcf)
- [Getting EndpointNotFoundException with NetNamedPipeBinding in C#; Need To Create Global Named Pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477813/getting-endpointnotfoundexception-with-netnamedpipebinding-in-c-need-to-create)
- [Connecting via named pipe from windows service (session#0) to desktop app (session #1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303154/connecting-via-named-pipe-from-windows-service-session0-to-desktop-app-sessi)